# Encoding NaN to JSON

Tags: json, servicestack

My server uses ServiceStack to produce JSON, and I need to send `double[]` arrays containing NaNs to the browsers.
Since there's no standard way of encoding NaNs in JSON, it's not surprising that
ServiceStack produces invalid JSON in presence of NaNs
(e.g. `[0,NaN,42]`). I chose string values as my custom representation of NaNs (and ±Inf by the way):
`[0,"NaN",42,"Inf","-Inf"]` as an example. (Of course I implemented the necessary post-processing on the browser side, too).
I managed to do it by setting `JsConfig<double>.RawSerializeFn` to an encoder function.
That was fine, until I realized that as a side effect all DTO properties of type `double`
disappear from their JSON representation when the value is 0.

EDIT: this can be demonstrated by `new KeyValuePair<double, double>(0, 1).ToJson()`
which returns `{"Key":0,"Value":1}` when `JsConfig<double>.RawSerializeFn` is unset,
but returns `{"Value":1}` when `JsConfig<double>.RawSerializeFn` is set.
This change is a side effect that I want to avoid. (But my core problem is the transmitting of NaNs *without* sacrificing zero-valued DTO properties.)

I browsed the [source code](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/62b8f40456336191e4384b9fd4a8d5f00868d28f/src/ServiceStack.Text/Common/WriteType.cs#L306)
of ServiceStack and it confirmed that the presence
of a custom `RawSerializeFn` activates the `Equals(DefaultValue,propertyValue)` check
(by causing `propertySuppressDefaultConfig==true`), which was omitted by default.
AFAICS the only way to avoid this check is setting `JsConfig.IncludeNullValues=true`,
which is bad because it cannot be done for `double` values only. I need the
default behavior: omitting properties with `null` values (for reference types) *and* include 0.0 double values in the generated JSON.

How to achieve these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [custom RawSerializeFn emits 0 values](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/dd9449b062a8941ad289b2947c2055c35b9e9ef7) in the latest version of [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text)

```
JsConfig<double>.IncludeDefaultValue = true;
JsConfig<double>.RawSerializeFn = d =>
    double.IsPositiveInfinity(d) ?
        "\"+Inf\""
    : double.IsNegativeInfinity(d) ?
        "\"-Inf\""
    : double.IsNaN(d) ?
        "\"NaN\""
    : d.ToString();

var doubles = new[] { 
    0.0, 1.0, double.NegativeInfinity, double.NaN, double.PositiveInfinity };

doubles.ToJson().Print(); // [0,1,"-Inf","NaN","+Inf"]

new KeyValuePair<double, double>(0, 1).ToJson().Print(); // {"Key":0,"Value":1}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not solve my problem. Sorry if I was not clear enough. I have updated the question, please see the EDIT paragraph.

Comment: @robert4 ok no worries I've just added a new `JsConfig<T>.IncludeDefaultValue` option for this which will generated the desired output. This is available from v4.0.36+ that's [now available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Thanks for your superfast response! This solution is OK.